# Можно ли сделать выбор языков с помощью списка или обязательно нужен select?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

---

Суть проблемы в следующем. Мне нужна языковая панелька, её обязательно верстать с помощью select>option? Или можно сделать просто списком? Если можно с помощью списка, то как вам мой вариант? Я уже пометил комментарием в коде, что блок .wrap-wrap мне нужен для позиционирования span-a и ul по центру по вертикали, но из этого вытекла вторая проблема, как сделать так, чтобы при наведении именно на ul блок .wrap-wrap получал свойство overflow: visible; ? Вообщем, буду рад услышать варианты!

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}


li{
  list-style: none;
}

.wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #444;
  position: relative;
}


/*wrap-wrap для позиционирования блока language и ul по центрну родительского */

.wrap-wrap{
  position: absolute;
  height: 27px;
  top:50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper span, .wrapper ul{
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  color: #fff;
  line-height: 20px;
}


.wrapper ul{
  padding-right: 30px;
}

.wrap-wrap ul li:hover .wrap-wrap{
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="wrap-wrap">
      <span>Language : </span>
        <ul>
            <li>English</li>
            <li>Deutch</li>
            <li>Russian</li>
          </ul>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: В настоящее время нет способа выбрать родительский элемент элемента в CSS. Тут либо что-то менять, либо на js делать

Comment: на jquery пример -> https://jsfiddle.net/kLw41g92/

Comment: Ок, но ответа на главный вопрос я так и не услышал. Меня интересовало, стоит ли вообще делать языковую панель с помощью ul? А через жс получается можно навешать событие на клик по ul , чтобы изменилось свойство overflow у родителя?

Comment: можно, никто этого не запрещает... но я бы не советовал так делать

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, как я понял вопрос - да, Вы можете так верстать списки, и более того, как правило их так и верстают. Я написал для Вас код-список, который раскрывается при наведении мыши и скрывается, когда курсор уходит. Я так же написал условие, что если в списке будет больше `10 li`, то высота установится в `200px` и `overflow:auto`. Если необходимо отправить выбранный вариант на почту или куда-то, то используйте вместо `output -> input`. Ну и конечно же со стилями я мало баловался. Просто пример, чтобы повысили знания. Успехов, друг!

```js
let output = document.querySelector('.wrap-wrap output'),
 li = document.querySelectorAll('.wrap-wrap li'),
 ul = document.querySelector('.wrap-wrap ul');

output.innerHTML = li[0].innerHTML;

 ul.onmouseover = function(){
  ul.style.height = (40 * li.length) + 40 + 'px';
  if(li.length >= 10){
   ul.setAttribute('style', 'height: 200px; overflow: auto;');
  }
 }
 ul.onmouseout = function(){
  ul.removeAttribute('style');
 }

 li.forEach(function(e){
  let text = e.innerHTML;
  e.addEventListener('click', function(){
   output.innerHTML = text;
  })
  
 })
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
 list-style: none;
}

.wrap-wrap {
 display: flex;
}
.wrap-wrap span, .wrap-wrap li, .wrap-wrap output {
 display: block;
 padding: 0 10px;
 height: 40px; line-height: 40px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
.wrap-wrap input {
 height: 40px;
 background: none;
 padding: 0 10px;
 border: 0; outline: 0;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
.wrap-wrap ul {
 margin-left: 10px;
 height: 40px;
  transition: 375ms;
  cursor: default;
 overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<section class="wrapper">
  <article class="wrap-wrap">
      <span>Language:</span>
        <ul>
   <output></output>
            <li>English</li>
            <li>Deutch</li>
            <li>Russian</li>
         </ul>
   </article>
</section>
```

Comment: прикольно! плюс Вам :) я бы только ещё добавил ul.removeAttribute('style'); в функцию клика по li - так будет органичнее

Comment: Спасибо, делюсь знаниями. Если удалять стайл по клику, тогда не вижу смысла в onmouseout. Думаю ТС сам уже поправит)

Comment: ну как же? а если пользователь навёл курсор, а потом передумал - список так и останется висеть раскрытым? так что смысл в onmouseout прямой

Comment: @humster_spb почему же? Там же функция на onmouseout удалить style=) Можете посмотреть нажав "выполнить код".

Comment: так Вы же сами пишете "Если удалять стайл по клику, тогда не вижу смысла в onmouseout". я Вам объясняю, в чём смысл - и того, и другого :))

Comment: Возможно я не правильно понял вас. Но я понял примерно так: если навел курсор мыши на цель, а после кликнул на дочерний элемент цели - скрыть список (удалить инлайн стиль). В таком случае не вижу смысла, ибо список все равно скроется, когда курсор будет за целью. В любом случае вы можете добавить свою версию, она рано или поздно пригодится кому-нибудь

Comment: "Если курсор за целью" - ключевое условие. Сейчас в Вашем решении получается, что человек кликнул на тот или иной язык, в output значение поменялось, а список не свернулся. Это как если бы в выпадающем меню Вы бы кликнули на пункт, страница открылась новая, а меню так и осталось бы развёрнуто, пока Вы не убрали мышь. Похоже на баг :)

Comment: свой вариант добавлять нет смысла - у Вас всё ок кроме этого одного момента =)

Comment: Тогда я все правильно понял, но считаю в данном случае это допустимо. Если хотите - предложите свой вариант или поправьте мой. Дополнительная информация всегда необходима в этой сфере UPD ну и не предлагайте ))